# Cell tower measurment reading

Tags: power, rf, cellular

I made some measurements near few cell towers and i have noticed that i get 2 values that is changing every few seconds.
For example i get a reading of 20uW/cm2 for few seconds and after that the value spikes to 60uW/cm2 for some seconds and again it go down to 20uW/cm2 and so on.
What is the reason for this phenomenon?

Thanks.

Comment: It feels like you're assuming the cell tower would output constant power. That assumption would be wrong! In addition to that, your channel is also time-variant, and you're *very* slow if you only look in second intervals. Compare this answer of mine:

Comment: Thanks Marcus,Yes,i have already read that link before and No i am not assuming that the output is constant,my point was why am i getting 20 value,after that it triple to 60,go back to 20 an so on(same values),what value should i relate to.I also didn't understood your sentence"you're very slow if you only look in second intervals"

Comment: So, now I'm confused. You say, you understand that the power is not constant. Then you ask which single power you want to refer to. That makes no sense. You **cannot** describe it with a single power. That's the point.

Comment: Re: "Slow": The power changes at intervals smaller than 1 ms; the channel between the mast and your receiver changes, depending on the scenario, on time scales between a couple milliseconds and maybe 500 ms. So, when you look at two received powers that were received seconds apart, basically *everything* has changed, many hundred times in between. Your receiver is like a particularly slow turtle trying to catch a cruise missile.

Comment: When you look on the map of all the deployment cell towers,there is a detail of the value of the power density(uW/cm2),among other details,for each one of a cell tower(value of the last checked date),which was measured at the place where there was the highest reading and it is a single value power value.May you explain that?

Comment: Yes. These maps are either *planning* maps for some specific quantile of power, like "power density is lower than that for X% of the time", for network planning things, **or** they are regulatory maps (which is morel likely here, but I don't know which maps you're referring to) and they give a maximum legal power density, which depends on the antenna placement, and has nothing to do with how much power density you'll measure (hopefully, otherwise that system is really on the border of illegality).

Comment: In short, they are either a result of *extensive statistics* over a series of observations of power, or they are just upper limits.

Comment: Okay,i got the idea that the emf meter detection is much much slower that the hundreds transmitting pulses of the cell tower in one seconds,but why do i get exactly the same values:20uW/cm2 and 60uW/cm2 over and over again.If the value of the transmitting power is changing hundreds of time in seconds,shouldn't the emf meter show/catch different values each time from all the changing values in that second?

Comment: I don't know your meter, but that's almost certainly an artifact of how it measures. There's nothing oscillating between the two same exact powers. Also, modern systems don't send isolated pulses.

Comment: Thanks Marcus,The link that you sent before didn't answer my question,but it has some good information about cell towers.I assume,as you advised and as i understood your explanation,that the changing reading related to the emf itself indeed,Thanks.

Comment: No, that's not all there is to it. As I already commented here, the channel between you and the emitter also quickly changes. I get the feeling you really don't even know what you're measuring there.